# How disable past and future dates in <p:calendar>?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, calendar

I need to disable all past dates from the current date and make available only the three upcoming dates from the current day in the `<p:calendar>` component from Primefaces. How to do this?

Comment: Remarkable... There is an example of this in the [PrimeFaces showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/calendar.xhtml) and it is mentioned in the PrimeFaces documentation.How hard can it be than to find... Seriously ;-( (please flag as not constructive ;-))

Answer (score 7):

You can use the `mindate` and `maxdate` attributes of the `<p:calendar>` component. For example:

```
<p:calendar mindate="#{dateBean.today}" maxdate="#{dateBean.todayPlusThree}" />
```

In the `dateBean` bean, you'd have (at least) two getters with content similar to this:

```
public Date getToday() {
   Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); 
   return c.getTime();
}

public Date getTodayPlusThree() {
   Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); 
   c.add(Calendar.DATE, 3);
   return c.getTime();
}
```

Comment: Did you register the `DateBean` as a JSF Managed Bean?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the maxdate and mindate as the partner said.

```
<p:calendar id="inputDataNaixement" maxdate="#{datesController.today}"></p:calendar>
```

And add a variable with the date of today into the Controller(ManagedBean) to use it in p:calendar

```
public Date today;

public Date getToday() {
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); 
       return c.getTime();
}
public void setToday(Date today) {
    this.today = today;
}
```